# TFS REST API: Get all tests results for a single test case

Tags: rest, tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-2015

I'm experimenting with the relatively new REST API for the TFS.
I can get single work items by ID, all their details (e.g. other linked work items by link) ... but I couldn't find any hint or example how to get all test results (test runs?) for a given test case.

Or do I have to "download" (get) all test results of all tests in all test suites of my plan to filter out manually the two or three tests results of my wanted test case?

Answer (score 1):

Test resulta are not associated with Test Cases directly. A test case could pass and fail On multiple Test plane as part of multiple Test suites.

You would need to first look up all of the plane and did that contain that test case, then guess at the context before getting the results.

If you use a suite ID then you can easily look up the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var testResults =Connection.teamProject.TestResults.ByTestId(testcase.Id);

var res = testResults.Where(testResult => testPointsIds.Contains(testResult.TestPointId)).ToArray<ITestCaseResult>();
```